# Disable the programs ability to add exceptions to windows firewall via the API

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-firewall-api

This is a problem with Windows Firewall that is very annoying from its introduction. And persist trough several versions of windows.

I have two questions:

Is it possible to be disabled or at least require confirmation in XP/2003 Server ?

Does UAC handles this in Vista/2008 server? If it does not - is there any way to disable it?

Comment: What are you using Windows Firewall anyway? Why not turn it off and use something better like ZoneAlarm

Answer (score 1):

Might be helpful -

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758407.aspx

From the document -

You cannot prevent a program from using the Windows Firewall API to add a port to the exceptions list. If you need to prevent this, contact the program vendor or read the program documentation to see if there is a way to disable the feature that listens for incoming traffic. This might prevent the program from using the Windows Firewall APIs.